# grails 2.3.1 Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: grails

I am getting the following error when I tried to create a new Employee in static scaffold:

> Error 500: Internal Server Error
>
> URI
>       /file-tracker/employee/save Class
>       org.hibernate.StaleStateException Message
>       Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
>
> Around line 38 of
>   grails-app/controllers/org/simpragma/EmployeeController.groovy
>
> Around line 191 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java

What is wrong ?

```
package org.xyz

class Employee {
    String name;
    String department;
    String role;
    String userId;
    String pw;

    static mapping = {
        table 'employee'
        version false
        id  name: 'userId'
        id generator: 'native'
    }

    static hasMany = [toAllocations: Allocation, fromAllocations: Allocation]

    static mappedBy = [toAllocations: 'toEmployee', fromAllocations: 'fromEmployee']
    static constraints = {
        department nullable : true
            role nullable : true    
    }
}

package org.xyz

class Allocation {

    static hasOne = [file:File, toEmployee:Employee, fromEmployee:Employee, remark:Remark]
    static mappedBy = [toEmployee: 'toAllocations', fromEmployee: 'fromAllocations' ]

    static constraints = {
        remark nullable: true
    }
}

package org.xyz

class File {
    String fileNumber;
    Date requestedDate;
    String requestedBy;
    String priority;
    Double budget;
    String requestedByDepartment;
    String subject;

    static mapping = {
        id  name: 'fileNumber'
        version false
        id generator: 'native'
    }   
    static hasMany = [allocations: Allocation]  
    static constraints = {
        fileNumber nullable : true
        priority nullable : true
        budget nullable : true
    }
}

package org.xyz

class Remark {
    String remark;
    Date remarkDate;

    static belongsTo =  [allocation: Allocation];
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for test purposes I was trying to assign my own id to object. I can't do that if id should be generated during save.